# Asus Sabertooth X99 will not turn on

Tags: asus

Got up this morning to find both monitors blank, no signal.
Carried out a mains off/on cycle and pressed the on button. There is a very brief moment of life and it shuts down. Without touching anything, it will keep trying to turn on, but same result each time. I have replaced the power supply, no change.
I then started unplugging devices with no change until I got to the 4 and 6 way 12v connections. If I unplug both, the power supply comes to life and stays on.
As these connections primarily supply extra power to the CPU, it appears I have either a dead CPU or something related to the 12V rails is shorted.
Thoughts please.

Update: Went and removed the CPU, tried powering the board again, the fault remains, so it seems the MB has a fault in the 12V system.

Replacement MB on order.